# How do I fix StackOverflowError in org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry in Tomcat 7.0.35

Tags: tomcat

We are running an old version of Tomcat, and a new web application has caused a stack trace like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
```

This has been mentioned at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53871, and later versions (like Tomcat 8) don't seem to be affected.

How can I fix this?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584495/unable-to-complete-the-scan-for-annotations-for-web-application-app-due-to-a/49650960#49650960

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since upgrading Tomcat was not an option, I needed a way to work around this issue.

As it turns out **Tomcat 7.0.47** has the same issue, but better reporting. When run locally the reporting showed me this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for 
annotations for web application [/api] due to a StackOverflowError. 
Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. 
The class hierarchy being processed was 
[org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean-
>org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean]
```

Once I found the offending jar file, I added it to the `catalina.properties` file like this:

`org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=bcprov*.jar`

This appears to have worked around the issue in the older version of Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to fix this for a long time, and of all the fixes I've tried this is the only one that actually works.

Comment: I added bcp*jdk15on.jar to DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip too -
 see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#JAR_Scanning

Answer (score 21):

I run into the same issue with a legacy project I got on recently. I found better solution here: [Avoid cyclic reference inheritance in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927880/avoid-cyclic-reference-inheritance-in-grails)

As it turned out I also had two bcprov-jdk on classpath. In my case these were:

```
bcprov-jdk15on
bcprov-jdk16
```

Since it is a multimodule Maven project, I used

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.bouncycastle`

to find where they come from. Then I removed the jdk16 since the up to date one is the jdk15on and it works.

Comment: this is the correct answer, helped a lot to remove multiple version of bcprov.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. For Tomcat 8.* and above, the property name has changed to `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip`.

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#JAR_Scanning

Inside Tomcat directory, edit `conf/catalina.properties` file, find `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` property and add the offending jars to the bottom of the list.

e.g

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\
annotations-api.jar,\
ant-junit*.jar,\
ant-launcher.jar,\
ant.jar,\
...
xmlParserAPIs.jar,\
xom-*.jar,\
bcprov*.jar
```