# Error in Tomcat to deploy Grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-2.0, tomcat8, grails-controller

I have a Grails (v. 2.5.3) application and when I deploy in Tomcat through option: **WAR file to deploy**, selecting the **war file** the following error appears. If I try an app easier (size, complexity, etc.), it works well.

However, if I copy manually the content of the war file to the Tomcat path: **pathTomcat/webapps/myApplication** when I run the application from manager, it works well. Any error appears.

**Error:**

```
11-May-2016 19:54:33.973 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/MYAPP.war de la aplicación web
11-May-2016 19:54:40.215 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/MYAPP] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2066)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2012)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1936)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1897)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 47 more
```

**Grails dependency report:**

```
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.5.3
    ...
    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
       \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
       \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
....

+--- org.grails.plugins:tika-parser:1.9.0
   \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:1.52
   \--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.52
   \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52
....

+--- org.grails.plugins:jasypt-encryption:1.3.1
   \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46
```

**Lib folder:**

[image]

**Solved with the following configuration in BuildConfig.groovy:**

```
compile ("org.grails.plugins:jasypt-encryption:1.3.1") {
            excludes "bcprov-jdk16"
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have 2 versions of the `org.bouncycastle` library

You can run `grails dependency-report` to check on your dependencies and make sure to server the lib only from 1 jar

Seems you have a bad guy `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46` so you'll need to remove and check which plugins pull this dependency and make sure to exclude it from the dependency so in your `BuildConfig.groovy` you will have

from [doc](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.7/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution)

> By default, Grails will not only get the JARs and plugins that you
>   declare, but it will also get their transitive dependencies. This is
>   usually what you want, but there are occasions where you want a
>   dependency without all its baggage. In such cases, you can disable
>   transitive dependency resolution on a case-by-case basis:
>
> A far more common scenario is where you want the transitive
>   dependencies, but some of them cause issues with your own dependencies
>   or are unnecessary. For example, many Apache projects have
>   'commons-logging' as a transitive dependency, but it shouldn't be
>   included in a Grails project (we use SLF4J). That's where the excludes
>   option comes in:
>
> ```
> runtime('com.mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16',
>         'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:1.6.1') {
>     excludes "xml-apis", "commons-logging"
> }
> // Or
> runtime(group:'com.mysql', name:'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.16') {
>     excludes([ group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis'],
>              [ group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' ],
>              [ name: 'commons-logging' ])
> ```

You will want to exclude `bcprov-jdk16` from your dependency

Comment: I added the report. Thanks for helping me. **Edit**: Response is too bigger and I can't add it.

Comment: check for specific entries about `org.bouncycastle`

Comment: Yes, it appears. I added it. Besides, I found this: [Link1.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927880/avoid-cyclic-reference-inheritance-in-grails) [Link2.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955410/how-do-i-fix-stackoverflowerror-in-org-apache-catalina-startup-contextconfig-pop)

Comment: right its something that appears from time to time and I think we faced it - had to remove a jar from "jar hell" and it was ok - good luck sometimes its not obvious; but with the report you should be able to see if/when the other version is used

Comment: And have I delete manually the jar? Does it exist automatic process that deletes it when the war file is generated, for example: typing in Build.config or template/war/web.xml?

Comment: I updated to include the plugins that pull these dependencies. I use tika-parser and jasypt. And now it appear three versions.