# Maven module has different versions of the same library

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Good day!

I have maven multimodule project. Contains war,jar and ear modules. When I try to start local Tomcat (web module exploded), got the following error:

> Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal
>   cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed
>   was
>   [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]

I have read this question [Avoid cyclic reference inheritance in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927880/avoid-cyclic-reference-inheritance-in-grails)
and found two version of jar: `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar` and `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar`

but still cannot understand how to solve the issue..
Thank you in advance!

```
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ desktop-app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building arm-data-entry 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version}: Plugin org.codehau
s.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version} or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ arm-data-entry ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sea-print 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version}: Plugin org.codehau
s.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version} or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ sea-print ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building setup-docs 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version}: Plugin org.codehau
s.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version} or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ setup-docs ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pdf-cuter 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version}: Plugin org.codehau
s.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version} or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ pdf-cuter ---
[INFO] ru.my-company.ea.old:pdf-cuter:jar:1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.icepdf.os:icepdf-core:jar:6.1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO]    +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO]    \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sea-web 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ sea-web ---
[INFO] ru.my-company.ea.old:sea-web:war:1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- ru.my-company.ea.old:pdf-cuter:jar:1.0.30-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.icepdf.os:icepdf-core:jar:6.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO] |        \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO]       \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]          +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]          \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]             \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building the-ear 1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version}: Plugin org.codehau
s.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:${gwt.version} or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:${gwt.version}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ the-ear ---
[INFO] ru.my-company.ea.old:the-ear:ear:1.0.30-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO]       \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]          +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]          \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO]             \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
........
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.698 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-07T11:26:32+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\Projects\sea-eclipse>
```