# Tomcat container failed to start due to cyclic dependency

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I'm getting below error when ever starting tomcat. The tomcat container failed to start and showing the StackOverflowError in log due to cyclic dependency. I tried setting the -Xss value as 4M but it doesn't help. Not able to figure out which is the exact jar that giving the dependency issue. I'm using tomcat 7.0.40.

Can someone help on this.

```
Dec 29, 2014 2:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/aricloud]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/aricloud]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/aricloud] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2179)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2126)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2001)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
```

Comment: It's caused by an illegal component scan in `bouncycastle`

Comment: Please See [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584495/unable-to-complete-the-scan-for-annotations-for-web-application-app-due-to-a)

Comment: @Eddie - I checked the maven dependency tree for bouncycastle. There are 2 artifacts downloading same bouncycastle jar but different version. Guess that was the problem. After excluding the same in one dependency tomcat doesn't give that error. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there is two versions of same library added on the application.
In my case it was bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.69.jar and bcprov-jdk16-143.jar.
Once i removed bcprov-jdk16-143.jar, the issue got solved.