# Tomcat stack overflow error when deploying a Vaadin war

Tags: tomcat, vaadin, xss, stack-overflow

After producing a "war" file (with a size of 90 Mbytes) in "production mode" (with Vaadin 19.0.9 and gradle) , the deployment process in Tomcat 9.0.52 is very slow and shows this error

```
Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/WEBPROP] due to a StackOverflowError. 
Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. 
The class hierarchy being processed was
  [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream]
```

This error is often produced, but not always.

The tomcat server is running in a Ubuntu 18 with 8 GBytes of RAM. The java version is 15.0.2 (both for this computer and the one used for development).

Any idea? Thanks

PS: Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WEBPROP]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)

    ... 37 more

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WEBPROP]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)

    ... 37 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/WEBPROP] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream]

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2404)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2342)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2294)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2264)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.scanWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:2172)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:2152)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1408)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1303)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    ... 38 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/WEBPROP] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream]

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2404)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2342)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2294)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2264)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.scanWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:2172)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:2152)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1408)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1303)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: I have added the stack trace. Thanls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584495/unable-to-complete-the-scan-for-annotations-for-web-application-app-due-to-a) seems to be for the same issue. According to that, the issue could be that the `DEROutputStream` is served by two different JARs, for example `bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar` and `bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar`. In that case, one needs to be excluded.

It is also worth of pointing out that Vaadin 19 is no longer receiving updates, the newest maintained version is 20 and 21 soon to be released, so upgrade is highly recommenned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Yes, you are right, bcproc-jdkXXXX.jar with different versions were present.

Comment: About Vaadin version 20.0.6, I have had some problems using the Anchor component, so I had to downgrade to version 19.0.9. Maybe, if this problem is solved, I will be very pleased to upgrade version. Thanks